# OpenCV Cmake unable to find ffmpeg lib

Tags: linux, opencv, ffmpeg, cmake, arm

I am trying to compile OpenCV with ffmpeg support for ARM Platform on a x86 host.

I downloaded and compiled ffmpeg for arm platform (both static - FFMPEG_ARM_LIB and dynamic libs - FFMPEG_ARM_LIB_SO)

When I run cmake in opencv, it gives the following -

```
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      **NO**
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
```

I changed the following flags to point to the lib paths of both ffmpeg static and dynamic libs-

1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. C_INCLUDE_PATH
3. CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
4. PKG_CONFIG_PATH
5. PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
6. PATH
7. CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH
8. CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH

However, the opencv is still not able to recognize the ffmpeg libs.

My FFMPEG compilation command was

```
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static\
 --cross-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi- --arch=armv7a\
 --target-os=linux --prefix=<path>
```

What am I doing wrong here?
1. Am I compiling the ffmpeg with the wrong option?
2. Am I missing some element in CMake which would make it point to the compiled ffmpeg lib for ARM on my system?

Comment: were you make to find a solution. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: it could happen if cmake can't find the 'pkg-config' executable. Could you please check that 'PKG_CONFIG_FOUND' is defined by adding the following line: 
message(STATUS "Package config: ${PKG_CONFIG_FOUND}")
to the opencv/CMakeLists.txt (somewhere after the find_package(PkgConfig QUIET) line)

Comment: did you find the solution? pls help, i'm in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have previously run CMake, it could have saved its outputs and just use it now instead of doing all the work from the beginning. Delete CMakeCache.txt file and run CMake one more time.

Answer (score 0):

1. add the PATH of ffmpeg's *.pc into PKG_CONFIG_PATH.
2. rm CMakeCache.txt.
3. cmake-gui.

It works with my situation.